# Regex to find a specific word between %%

Tags: regex, twig

I have a text of data and want to find a specific word using regex.
I want to find `%Slideshow-12345%` from the data using regex.

```
{% set keys = test|regex_match_all("/%.*?%/ ") %}
```

The keys displays array of all match found.

Can you please help me with Regex to just find `%Slideshow%`

Comment: You need to be more clear: do you want to find `%SlideShow-12345%`, `%Slideshow%`, or `%Slideshow-` followed by a string of digits and a percent sign?

Comment: @MichaelBurr followed by string of any numbers

Comment: @bobblebubble Thanks it worked. 

Comment: This was the regex that worked: [`%Slideshow[^%]*%`](https://regex101.com/r/NSooTE/1) (the [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^%]*` matches any amount of any character that is not `%`)